# Which all processes are using shared library

Tags: unix

I have a shared library(.so file) on UNIX.
I need to know what all running processes are using it.
Do unix provide any such utility/command?

Answer (score 5):

You can inspect the contents of `/proc/<pid>/maps` to see which files are mapped into each process. You'll have to inspect every process, but that's easier than it sounds:

```
$ grep -l /lib/libnss_files-2.11.1.so /proc/*/maps
/proc/15620/maps
/proc/22439/maps
/proc/22682/maps
/proc/32057/maps
```

This only works on the Linux `/proc` filesystem, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution would be to use the [lsof](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html) command

```
[root@host]# lsof /lib/libattr.so.1
COMMAND     PID USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE   NODE NAME
gdm-binar 11442 root mem    REG    8,6 30899 295010 /lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
gdm-binar 12195 root mem    REG    8,6 30899 295010 /lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
```

This should work not only for `.so` files but any other files, dirs, mount points, etc.

N.B. `lsof` displays all processes that use a file, so there is a very remote possibility of a false positive if is a process that opens the `*.so` file but not actually use it. If this is an issue for you, then [Marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428588/which-all-processes-are-using-shared-library/4428672#4428672) would be the way to go.

Comment: This is a great tip. Thanks Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

Do in all directories of interest

```
ldd * >ldd_output
vi ldd_output
```

Then look for the the library name, e.g. “aLib.so”. This shows all modules linked to e.g. "aLib.so"